# Solving logarithmic equations without calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Hi I am stuck on this question 
$$
\log_x 10= 5 (\log_{10} x) +4
$$
The answer key gives the solutions $x = 10^{1/5}$ and $x = 1/10$.

Comment: Do you mean $\log_x 10=5 (\log x)+4$?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Can you use mathjax? It would make your equation far easier to read.

Comment: Yeah I will and it's the equation you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

If you meant $\log_x 10=5 \log x+4$ and the RHS logarithm is base $10$,

Use the change of base formula to write $\frac{\log 10}{\log x}=5 \log x +4.$

Then write $0= 5\log^2 x +4 \log x -1$. Set $t=\log x$, giving a quadratic $0=5t^2+4t-1$. Can you solve the quadratic?

**Edit:** Note that $\log_{a} a=1$.